# Delphi - How to correctly register a custom graphic class since Rio 10.3.3

Tags: delphi, components, registration, delphi-10.3-rio, timage

So I'm developing a graphic library providing a custom SVG image format which may be used within a TPicture, or any VCL component supporting a graphic image, like e.g a TImage. I wrote and maintain my library package since the XE7 compiler version, and my code is backward compatible until the XE2 version.

In order to declare my custom graphic format to the IDE, I call the following code from the `initialization` section of my graphic class

```pascal
Vcl.Graphics.TPicture.RegisterFileFormat('svg', 'Scalable Vector Graphics', TWSVGGraphic);
```

However this seems to no longer works since the last RAD Studio 10.3.3 Rio version. I already faced a similar issue in the past, for which I could find a solution:
[Delphi - How to correctly register a graphic class since XE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507846/delphi-how-to-correctly-register-a-graphic-class-since-xe8)

So, apparently Embarcadero changed the rules since the 10.3.3 Rio version. Once again. My graphic class is no longer registered correctly since this version. Sometimes it is, sometimes it isn't. For example, when I open my IDE for the first time, it isn't. When I try to debug my package in design time, it is. When I try to run a project, sometimes it is, sometimes it isn't.

Has someone faced a similar issue? Are the rules about the `initialization` section changed in the most recent compiler versions? Finally, what the hell is wrong with my code?

Or perhaps I still not understand how to correctly register a graphic class in Delphi, even after so many years. In this case, I would be very grateful if someone may explain me how to correctly register a graphic class, in order to never more facing a such issue in the future.

Comment: As many people liked this post, but unfortunately nobody has the solution, I deduce that I'm not the only one who is facing a such issue. For that reason I opened an issue report on the Embarcadero website: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-27341

Comment: Where do you actually call Vcl.Graphics.TPicture.RegisterFileFormat? Are you sure it is already called when you try to test it? Are you sure it's the correct place to call it?

Comment: As I said: "In order to declare my custom graphic format to the IDE, I call the following code from the initialization section of my graphic class". AFAIK it's the good place to call registration functions, because the initialization section is supposed to be called once when the package's DLL is initialized. At least it worked well until the first 10.3 Rio version, but it seems that something changed since Rio 10.3.3 (perhaps even since 10.3.2). But also as I said: "perhaps I still not understand how to correctly register a graphic class in Delphi". Any help would be welcome if it's the case.

Comment: You can't couple your graphic class with a project, initialization is the only place to call RegisterFileFormat.

Comment: And it is the place called for TJPEGImage, TPngImage and TGIFImage

Comment: I've done this in 10.4.1 
`TPicture.RegisterFileFormat('XYZ', 'Not a format', TImprovedJPEG)` to work around a bug in TJpegImage